# How do I set top left position as the anchor for a node (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, coordinates

Is there a way to position a node in terms of left/right coordinates of bounding rectangle? It appears to me that I can only specify center position.

Comment: Do you mean placing the text on the north west corner of the node instead of its center? You can check the `label` mechanism.

Comment: the other option would be placing a node by specifying the coordinates of its corner, which is done using the `anchor` option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to left- or right-align the node at a given coordinate, use the `anchor = east` / `anchor=west` option on the node. Here is an example for center, right and left alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \node at (2,2) {gnarply};
    \draw (2,2)--(3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \node[anchor=west] at (2,2) {gnarply};
    \draw (2,2)--(3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \node[anchor=east] at (2,2) {gnarply};
    \draw (2,2)--(3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]